# Symbolic simplification and ordering terms in R

Tags: r, symbolic-math

I would like to simplify symbolic expressions, which end users provide as arguments to a function, in such a way that the result is always an expression of the following form: c_1*A + c_2*B + c_3*C = c_4, where all c-terms are numerical constants, and capital letters are unknowns.

Thus, if a user provides the expression:

.2*A + 3*B + 2*B + 2 = C -5,

this should simplify to:
.2*A + 5*B -1*C = -7

The furthest I've come with this is by searching for symbolic simplification. The package Deriv can simplify some expressions by removing brackets etc., but it doesn't order terms as required.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to go about this in R, without introducing any dependencies other than on other R-packages? Thank you sincerely!